# Why HF_TASKS_AUTO not recognized from fastai?

Tags: tokenize, fast-ai, huggingface-tokenizers

This is PIP install that I did

```
!pip install ohmeow-blurr==0.0.6
!pip install datasets==1.3.0 -qq
!pip install fsspec==2021.7.0
```

This is the library imports that I did

```
import ast
import torch
from fastai.text.all import *
from transformers import *
from blurr.data.all import *
from blurr.modeling.all import *
```

I tried using fastai2 but this is the error that I get

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [16], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import ast
      2 import torch
----> 3 from fastai2.text.all import *
      4 from transformers import *
      8 from blurr.data.all import *

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastai2\text\all.py:1, in <module>
----> 1 from ..basics import *
      2 from ..callback.all import *
      3 from .core import *

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastai2\basics.py:1, in <module>
----> 1 from .data.all import *
      2 from .optimizer import *
      3 from .callback.core import *

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastai2\data\all.py:1, in <module>
----> 1 from ..torch_basics import *
      2 from .core import *
      3 from .load import *

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastai2\torch_basics.py:4, in <module>
      2 from .imports import *
      3 from .torch_imports import *
----> 4 from .torch_core import *
      5 from .layers import *

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastai2\torch_core.py:312, in <module>
    309         if isinstance(f, (MethodWrapperType, BuiltinFunctionType, BuiltinMethodType, MethodType, FunctionType)):
    310             setattr(TensorBase, fn, get_f(fn))
--> 312 _patch_tb()
    314 # Cell
    315 class TensorCategory(TensorBase): pass

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastai2\torch_core.py:308, in _patch_tb()
    306 for fn in dir(t):
    307     if fn in skips: continue
--> 308     f = getattr(t, fn)
    309     if isinstance(f, (MethodWrapperType, BuiltinFunctionType, BuiltinMethodType, MethodType, FunctionType)):
    310         setattr(TensorBase, fn, get_f(fn))

RuntimeError: tensor.H is only supported on matrices (2-D tensors). Got 1-D tensor.
```

This is the task that I wanted to add but somehow not being able to

```
task = HF_TASKS_AUTO.TokenClassification
```

This the error that I get from the code above

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The API had to be updated to work on kaggle ... you should be able to simply use `get_hf_objects` from the `utils` module ...

```
from blurr.text.utils import get_hf_objects

hf_arch, hf_config, hf_tokenizer, hf_model = get_hf_objects(
    "microsoft/deberta-v3-small",
    model_cls=AutoModelForSequenceClassification
)
```